# Связывание таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
Employee (
id int primary key auto_increment,
name char(255), departament_id int,
foreign key (departament_id) references Departament (id))
```

и

```
Departament (
id int  primary key auto_increment,name char(255));
```

Нужно чтобы данные из `Department` отображались в `Employee`.

пишу:

`select e.name from Employee e inner join Departament D on e.departament_id = D.id;`

Но в таблице `Employee` ничего не происходит. 
Подскажите что я не так делаю?

Comment: А что должно происходить? И при чём тут Java?

Comment: а что по вашему должно произойти в таблице Employee? Вы делаете запрос, запрашиваете одно поле name. И каким боком здесь Java?

Comment: Как я понимаю, в таблице Employee столбец departament_id должен заполниться данными из таблицы Departament при обновлении таблицы.
А Java потому, что вся работа происходит в IDEA, соответственно пишется нас java, может я неправильно понял теги, исправлюсь)

Comment: *Как я понимаю* Огорчу. Вы понимаете совершенно неправильно. Попробуйте `select e.name, d.name from Employee e inner join Departament d on e.departament_id = d.id;`, и постарайтесь понять, что получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во время запросов на выборку с таблицами ничего не происходит, если вы хотите вывести данные из двух таблиц вы их объединяете с помощью join, а после слова select перечисляете список полей, значения которых вы хотите увидеть. Например:

```
 select e.id as employee_id, e.name, e.department_id, d.name from Employee e inner join Departament d on e.departament_id = d.id;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, после нескольких часов изучения и написание запросов стало понятно!